# Doubt on problem regarding limit infimum of indicator functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, lebesgue-measure

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $f_n = \chi_{E_n}$, then is:

$$\liminf f_n = \liminf \chi_{E_n} = \chi_{\liminf E_n} ?$$

It's the third inequality I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \chi_{E_n}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{$x \notin E_n$ for finitely many $n$}\\
0 & \text{$x \notin E_n$ for infinitely many $n$}
\end{cases}
= \chi_{\bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{k \ge n} E_k}(x)
= \chi_{\liminf_{n \to \infty} E_n}(x).$$